# Entity framework, adding custom entity to diagram

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using the entity framework that comes with 3.5sp1, and I'm trying to add a custom entity that I will propulate with searchresults from a stored procedure. But I have problems with the designer....... when I pick "Add + Entity" and give it a name, and hit save, the whole diagram stops working...... blah entities namespace could not be found..... all the other entities have lost its reference or summet. Works when I add a "table" to it that exists in database. But when custom it screws everything up.

How should I fix this? I've imported the function, I just need to add an entity for it...

I've read http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/03/13/mapping-stored-procedure-results-to-a-custom-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx but I cant get to step 3 since of all the errors when saving on step 2.

/M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I must have the primary key option checked when adding entity.